# Is there a way to determine what the rpm file permissions should be?

Tags: linux, permissions, rpm

I am working on hardening an instance of [Fedora CoreOS](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/getting-started/) and I am using [OpenSCAP](https://www.open-scap.org/) to perform a security scan to enumerate issues that need to be fixed.  One of the issues is that some of the permissions are not as expected for various RPM packages.

The recommended fix is to use `sudo rpm --setperms PACKAGENAME` to fix issues.  However, with CoreOS it fails for several files because `/usr` is a read-only file system by design.  The proper way to fix this would be to update the CoreOS ignition file to set the mode during deployment.

Is there any way to extract what `sudo rpm --setperms PACKAGENAME` is *trying* to do so I can use those to build my ignition file by hand?  Essentially I want to see what mode the package is expecting files to have but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get that information.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do this by using [tags](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-queryformat-tags.html) for the `--queryformat` option as follows:

```
rpm -q --queryformat="[%{FILEMODES:perms} %{FILENAMES}]" PACKAGENAME
```

Where `PACKAGENAME` is the name of the package you're querying.  If you want to get *every* file for *all* packages you can use `-ql` like this:

```
rpm -ql --queryformat="[%{FILEMODES:perms} %{FILENAMES}]"
```

Comment: slighlty better is to use a new line:
`rpm -q --queryformat="[%{FILEMODES:perms} %{FILENAMES}\n]" PACKAGENAME`